# Unicode doesn't work on big sites. Using windows 8

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, unicode

I get ï¿½ or a question mark in a diamond. What does it mean? It does it on both chrome and firefox.

Comment: What qualifies as a "big site"? Lots of HTML? Javascript-heavy? Scrollbar is long? Etc...

Comment: Can you provide an example of a specific site? Do you have any web proxies running (is this at work?)? This can happen when interpreting an invalid UTF-8 page as UTF-8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366912/reading-file-from-windows-and-linux-yields-different-results-character-encoding/6367675#6367675

Comment: Ive noticed it on several sites, but main one im on is http://valoria.infinite-muse.com/index.php?act=idx Also i dont have any web proxies running, but my wireless automatically sets a proxy according to my network settings and i dunno how to stop it

Comment: Can you point to a specific part of that page where this occurs? I suspect your proxy is mangling the site. (If you are on school, work or public wireless - they often set proxies. Incidentally, you also shouldn't send any sensitive data to a non-HTTPS site over those proxies if you care about privacy or security - they can sniff passwords, etc.)

Comment: It occurs on any special characters, be it the solid --- lines under 'site news' beside each link, or the dot between 'logout' and account(forme). It happens in names as well. Like Korbl has the o with two dots above it, it turns into what i posted above.

Comment: Its at my house, i rent a room from a friends aunt. Is there anyway to turn off the proxy?

Comment: (As [suggested by @JourneymanGeek](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19510272#19510272)) You could also try the TOR Browser Bundle - not permanently, but it would allow us to confirm or rule out the proxy or other network filtering as being the issue. You could also register an account here and join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) for more extended troubleshooting/guiding - comments and answers aren't really suited for a lot of back-and-forth, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Those characters appear when something is invalid on the page. Specifically, they are used by UTF-8 [to represent invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366912/reading-file-from-windows-and-linux-yields-different-results-character-encoding/6367675#6367675), and can be summed up as an invalid attempt to read non-UTF-8 data as UTF-8, followed by the opposite.

Normally, this is caused by one of two things:

- The site you are connecting to has encoding issues on the server side. This is unlikely if others cannot reproduce your problem.
- You have a proxy or other filter that is incorrectly configured, and mangles the text.

---

Based on your comments, your issue is likely the latter. Since your proxy is set by the network, you might not be able to disable it - ideally, you'd talk to your network admin (your friend's aunt, presumably) about it, assuming they know what they're doing. Otherwise, there are a couple options:

- You can *try* to unset the proxy on your local computer. That means unsetting it from your browser - you can search for specific instructions for Firefox and Chrome. Firefox in particular has an option to ignore system-wide proxy settings, in the event that they get re-set when you reconnect to the network (Chrome, IIRC, can also do so with a command-line startup option). This may or may not work depending on how the network is set up, but it is the best option performance-wise.
- You can tunnel your connection through a VPN to bypass this proxy entirely. This might have added costs (pay for a VPN, reduced performance) involved.
- You can stick to HTTPS sites only. As long as you don't accept any certificates your browser identifies as untrustworthy, then your communication should be guaranteed secure and unintercepted, therefore the proxy cannot mangle the content. Obviously, this is impractical for a large number of sites.

I'd also note that there are serious privacy and security implications of having a proxy like this set, especially with you unaware of it. Specifically, any passwords, etc., sent in the clear can be intercepted and viewed by the network admin. They can also see all the data you send/receive that is unencrypted (not HTTPS, VPN). Of course, it's also possible to do all this silently, but using a broken proxy just makes it kinda obvious - I cannot think of a benign reason for this.